# Combine digital elevation model (DEM) with point layer (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, dem, point

I have two layers: 
The first one is a digital elevation model (DEM) as GeoTiff. The second is a point vector layer (start and end of street segments).

What I want to do:
Add elevation information to the point layer (as the new attribut hight) from the raster DEM.

My first plan: 
Convert DEM to vektor and than intersect with point layer. Problem here: Conversion to vektor takes extremely long time, as its a 30x30m resolution.

Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to convert your raster; I see what you're getting at, but there's an easier way - the **Point Sampling Tool** plugin.

Once you install this plugin, go to **Plugins > Analyses > Point Sampling tool**

[image]

Choose your point layer, and the raster band(s) you want to sample from at each point. It will also allow you to sample from vector layers. It'll create a new layer with the values added as attributes to each point.

If you don't want it as a separate layer, you can use **join** to pull the values back from this new layer into your original layer.

Comment: Yes, thats the solution to my problem!